# ReactChart is not showing up

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

I am using react-chart for rendering line chart in my application. line chart in not showing up. Its creating a canvas inside div tag with id "main1".

lchart.js file:

```
var React = require('React');
var LineChart = require("react-chart").Line;
var ReactDOM = require('ReactDOM');
var Chart = require('chart.js');

Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
var chartData = [
     {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
     },
     {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
     },
     {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
     }
];

var LChart = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (<LineChart data={chartData} width="600" height="250" redraw/>);
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<LChart />, document.getElementById('main1'));
```

index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main1"></div>
    <script src="lchart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your index.html?

Comment: @Hussein Alkaf added index.html file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using **react-chartjs V1**:

The data you pass into the **LineChart component** `<LineChart ... />` should follow this pattern:

```
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]
};
```

For more information visit the Chart.js V 1.1.1 documentation [Chart.js V1.1.1: Line Chart documentation](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v1.1.1/docs/01-Line-Chart.md)